# Как проверить ссылку на путь к файлу?

Tags: php

Как можно проверить ссылку (URL) на наличие пути к файлу? Имеется ввиду: `http://link.link/path/file.exe`. То есть запретить все ссылки такого вида.

Comment: логично это делать на уровне *http-сервера*. во-первых, у него для этого (обычно) есть все возможности, во-вторых, это гораздо производительнее, чем (дополнительное) обращение к интерпретатору (в данном случае — `php`).

Comment: На уровне сервера - это что имеет ввиду?

Comment: имеется ввиду используемый ***http**-сервер* — *apache*, *nginx* и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: вы же сегодня уже спрашивали, и вам что-то отвечали

Answer (score -1, accepted):

при условии что ссылка у Вас такого вида `http://link.link/path/file.exe` можно регуляркой

```
/\.(?:exe)$/i
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто по ссылке - никак, любой URL может соответствовать некоторому файлу,  отдаваемому сервером.

- Такой: http://link.link/path/file.exe
- и такой: http://link.link/path/file
- и такой: http://link.link/path/form.php?aaaa
- и такой: http://link.link/path/something#!/something
- и даже такой: http://link.link

Но сервер может, получив ссылку, начать скачивать файл и, получив достаточно байт, прервать скачивание и сверить сигнатуру файла по какому-то принципу. Например, проверить наличие в файле PE-заголовка. После чего сообщить пользователю, что его URL не годится.